# Python: Interrupting the terminal-bell/system-bell sound to simulate morse-code DOT/DASH messages

Tags: python, windows, shell, cmd, morse-code

I'm working on a script which emulates morse code in the terminal by simulating morse-code sounds by triggering the default system bell sound. ***DASH*** sounds are created by letting the bell run for 0.80 seconds, ***DOT*** sounds are created by only letting the bell run for 0.20 seconds (by interrupting it).

I am trying to make this an OS-independent script so not looking to use any OS-specific libraries. But I am using Windows currently.

***I am so close!*** When my code runs in the terminal, ***DASH*** sounds work correctly, but if a character (eg '***b***') ends in a dot, the character's final ***DOT*** sound is not interrupted, and instead sounds like a ***DASH,*** leading to an error in the sound.

The way I'm getting the ***DOT/DASH*** sounds is by interrupting the bell with another bell (via threading)

Eg: If the message is 'ab' the sound should be:

- "DOT-DASH {SMALL_PAUSE} DASH-DOT-DOT-***DOT***"

What my code outputs (sound-wise) is:

- "DOT-DASH {SMALL_PAUSE} DASH-DOT-DOT-***DASH***"

I need to interrupt the final bell *somehow* so it only lasts 0.2 seconds, and I don't know how to do this without calling another bell.

What can I do to correctly control the sound's duration?

Code (working - no 3rd party libs):

```py
import sys
import threading
import time

# Allows message inputs to convert to morse by making system beep

# Morse codes: char: [beep_1, beep_2, beep_n....]

DASH = 0.80  # only run the bell for this duration before interrupting
DOT = 0.20  # only run the bell for this duration before interrupting
CHAR_PAUSE = 1.5  # run no bells for this duration
SPACE_PAUSE = 3.5  # run no bells for this duration

# ISSUE: if the character ends in a DOT, it sounds like a dash with my current script.
# Note I've only translated up to 'e' currently
morse = {
    'a': [DOT, DASH], # Sounds Fine as last character is a DASH
    'b': [DASH, DOT, DOT, DOT],  # Sounds right till last DOT (sounds like dash)
    'c': [DASH, DOT, DASH, DOT],  # Sounds right till last DOT (sounds like dash)
    'd': [DASH, DOT, DOT],  # Sounds right till last DOT (sounds like dash)
    'e': [DOT],  # Will sound like a DASH - not good
        }

def beep_function(char, beep):
    """play system beep sound for {beep} duration before interruption"""
    sys.stdout.write('\a')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(beep)


threads = []
message = 'ab'  # You'll notice the last beep in 'b' is not right
message = message.lower()
for char in message:
    if char != ' ':
        for beep in morse[char]:
            t = threading.Thread(target=beep_function(char, beep))
            threads.append(beep)
            t.start()
        time.sleep(CHAR_PAUSE)
    if char == ' ':
        time.sleep(SPACE_PAUSE)  # For when I eventually have an entire message
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but the SHOUTING is rather irksome, and your approach seems fundamentally rather brittle.

Comment: Drive-by downvotes tend to be compensated by drive-by upvotes over time if your question is any good. Just hang in there, and in the meantime, maybe try to disable Caps Lock.

Comment: It looks like you need a system sound of silence for this implementation

Comment: @Sergey Shubin that’s an excellent idea and I had thought that previous and tried to see if there are parameters I could pass to bell on the command line, but had no luck. Any thoughts on how to implement this?